# How can I write a simple regex to match an optional middle group?

Tags: python, regex

Say I have the following code in python:

```py
import re 
a = 'AA_BB_CC' 
b = 'AA_CC' 
regex = r'(.+)_((.+)_)?(.+)' 
groups_a = re.search(regex, a).groups()  # ('AA_BB', None, None, 'CC')
groups_b = re.search(regex, b).groups()  # ('AA', None, None, 'CC')
```

I would like to have a regex where `groups_a = ('AA', 'BB', '_', 'CC')` and `groups_b = ('AA_BB', None, None, 'CC')`.
My current regex is capturing `'AA_BB'` in the first group of `groups_a`. How should I change my regex?

Comment: I don't understand the expected outputs.  Can you explain them?

Comment: I rephrased the question. Hope it's a little bit clearer

Comment: Does `([^\W\d_]{2})_??` yield correct results?

Comment: Is it really necessary to capture the `_` as well? What is the intended output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use non-greedy quantificators (`+?`) (except for the last one; or you can put the regex within `^$`, if it is guaranteed to take the whole line),
2. Make the second group non-capturing (`(?`):

`regex = r'(.+?)_(?:(.+?)_)?(.+)'`.

https://regex101.com/r/6GWAff/2

Comment: Your regex looks interesting, I think it just needs to use a greedy quantificator in the last group otherwise it won't match 'CC' but only 'C'. Something like `(.+?)_(?:(.+?)_)?(.+)?` perhaps?

Comment: Or add `^` and `$`. Correcting, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an optional middle part and use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html@negated) `[^` instead to not cross the `_` boundary

```
^([^_]+)(?:_([^_]+))?_([^_]+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([^_]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any char except `_`
- `(?:_([^_]+))?` Optionally match `_` and capture in group 2 any char except `_`
- `_` Match `_`
- `([^_]+)`  Capture group 3, match 1+ times any char except `_`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ONVR0d/1)